# Remove stocks that do not have at least m observations with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I ran this command like this;

```
df.groupby("Ticker").size() > 89
```

And I got this result;

[image]

And I made the code like this, but error is given.

```
df.loc[df.groupby("Ticker").size() > 89]
```

I want to remove stocks that do not have at least 89 observations.

Comment: Where is the result?

Comment: I uploaded my result as image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for repeat counts, so possible filtering:

```
df[df.groupby("Ticker")['Ticker'].transform('size') > 89]
```

Or use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df[df['Ticker'].map(df["Ticker"].value_counts()) > 89]
```

If want use your solution and need filter aggregate counts use:

```
s = df.groupby("Ticker").size() 
s = s[s > 89]
```

Comment: Hello, in df.groupby("Ticker").size() > 89, how can get stocks with a value of True?

For example, in my attached result, BMX and CAL,...